# Как выделить область вокруг пикселя и заставить кликер игнорировать её?

Tags: python, auto

Есть кликер на Python, который ищет пиксель с нужным цветом и кликает на него раз в какое-то кол-во времени.
Как можно выделить область вокруг этого пикселя, и если кликер уже сработал на этот пиксель, то игнорировать область с заданным размером?
Хорошо, если он будет забывать, что это была за область, до следующего клика.

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from mss import mss
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard

monitor = {
    "left": 1,
    "top": 1,
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1080,
}

# Поиск цвета на экране
def find_color(our_color, monitor={}):
    # Возмём кусок экрана
    m = mss()

    # Получаем пиксель с экрана монитора
    img = m.grab(monitor)

    # Преобразуем этот пиксель в матрицу
    img_arr = np.array(img)

    # Поиск цвета (b, g, r, alpha)
    our_map = (our_color[2], our_color[1], our_color[0], 255)
    indexes = np.where(np.all(img_arr == our_map, axis=-1))
    our_crd = np.transpose(indexes)
    return our_crd


# Искомый цвет
our_color = [255, 13, 0]

while True:
    time1 = time.time()
    result = find_color(our_color, monitor)
    time2 = time.time()
    if result.__len__():
        x = result[0][1] + monitor.get('left')
        y = result[0][0] + monitor.get('top')
        pg.moveTo(x, y)
        pg.click(x,y)


    # Ожидание
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: До цикла определите пустой список к примеру - в цикле сохраняйте туда координаты последнего клика и через условие проверяйте\очищайте список.

Comment: Понимаете, вокруг пикселя ещё некоторое количество таких же, нужно, чтобы он определил любой из них, запомнил область вокруг, и следующий клик не должен быть в этой области. (Это кликер для динамического изображения, грубо говоря, масса пикселей вылезает на пару секунд и скрывается обратно, нужно чтобы он не искал все пиксели в этой массе, а выбрал любой, нажал 1 раз и эту область не трогал)

Comment: Алгоритм в целом не меняется. Сохраняете координаты последнего клика. При следующем проходе цикла сверяете новые координаты со старыми + добавляя диапазон. к примеру х =5 у=5. Ваша задача проверить не входят ли новые координаты по x,y в диапазон x,y=[0, 5, 10]

Comment: Как проверить условие, если точки, сохраняющиеся в список, начинающиеся со второй (list[1]), не могут быть проверены в условии, так как до них не дошёл цикл?

Comment: В смысле? Как я понимаю вам нужно проверить только что бы новые координаты, не совпадали со старыми. Или я не верно уловил вашу мысль?

Comment: Есть игра. Есть условное лицо, состоящее из N пикселей одинакового цвета. Сработав на один пиксель,  код может найти ближайший к нему, чего делать не нужно (не нужно дважды кликать на 1 лицо). Другие лица отличаются от этого своим расстоянием между ними. Нужно, чтобы проходил 1 цикл и на следующем цикле близлежащие пиксели того же цвета игнорировались. (Я не знаю, как организовать проще кликер, который будет кликать по объекту 1 раз, который динамически вылезает, затем скрывается обратно (он не постоянно на экране)).

Comment: можете приложить пример изображения?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4ZcqydD

Comment: Может тогда лучше использовать не поиск по пикселю, а воспользоваться opencv для поиска условных лиц? Сразу со всей картинке получить координаты всех лиц и отстрелятся по ним.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример с OpenCV

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Загрузка исходника, тут можно передать скриншот. 
image = cv2.imread('QsAY5r3.png')

# Папка с шаблонами
templates_folder = 'img2'

# Проход по каждому шаблону в папке
for template_file in os.listdir(templates_folder):
    template_path = os.path.join(templates_folder, template_file)
    print(template_path)
    # Шаблон
    template = cv2.imread(template_path)

    # Совпадение по шаблону
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    # Порог "хороших" совпадений
    threshold = 0.95

    # Позиции, где совпадение превышает порог
    locations = np.where(result >= threshold)

    # Рисуем прямоугольник по полученной позиции и выводим координаты центра
    for loc in zip(*locations[::-1]):
        top_left = loc
        bottom_right = (loc[0] + template.shape[1], loc[1] + template.shape[0])
        center = ((top_left[0] + bottom_right[0]) // 2, (top_left[1] + bottom_right[1]) // 2)

        cv2.rectangle(image, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        

        # Выводим координаты центра
        print(f"Шаблон: {template_file}, Центр совпадения: {center}")

# Наш результат
cv2.imshow('Найденные места', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite('detected_lines_with_centers.jpg', image)
```

Картинка для поиска:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что искал (картинки из папки 'img2'):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Формат вывода координат:

```
img2\1.png
Шаблон: 1.png, Центр совпадения: (729, 323)
img2\2.png
Шаблон: 2.png, Центр совпадения: (1114, 462)
```

Вот как раз по ним можете и откликаться.

Пример для создания скриншота:

```
import pyautogui

left = 33
top = 67
width = 950
height = 520 

screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(left, top, width, height))   
screenshot = np.array(screenshot)
screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```